# Add Payment Details to a Sandbox Account to test IAP on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm testing purchasing a new product through the app I'm working on, and every time I put in the iTunes account for the sandbox user I created, I get a prompt that says "Add Payment Details".

According to the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html I shouldn't have to do this.

I've created and deleted probably 5 different Sandbox accounts to test this purchase, but each time I am asked to input payment details.  Even if I put payment details in, I get thrown back out of iTunes with "Connection Timeout"

[image: Payment Required for Sandbox]

Are the Apple Sandbox servers down?  Did  something change within the last month on testing IAP's?  I was able to test a month ago, but now I cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm experiencing this issue only with Free Trial subscription. Other subscription options with no free trial and IAPs work fine.

It seems Apple servers are not working fine for Free Trial subscriptions since thursday/friday.

Check this out: [All sandbox testers created through iTunes Connect request "Payment Information Required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589757/all-sandbox-testers-created-through-itunes-connect-request-payment-information?answertab=active#tab-top)

Have you tried other IAPs?

Comment: Thanks.  Seems to have been an Apple issue :P.  Really kills the timeline when their system is broken for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too on Friday and yesterday, but it appears to be fixed now. Try it again; if you still have problems, try creating a new sandbox test account and trying again with that one.