# All sandbox testers created through iTunes Connect request "Payment Information Required"

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm having an issue recently that I didn't seem to run into before with my iOS sandbox testers and In-App Purchases.  I've done the following:

1. Create a new sandbox tester that hasn't been used before.  Assign to United States.
2. Log out of all iTunes accounts on the device.
3. Open app and go through In-App Purchase flow.
4. Log in via the new itunes sandbox account.

This usually works for me.  But now I'm getting a prompt that says "Payment Information Required - To subscribe, add a new payment method.  You'll only be charged when your trial ends. [Environment: Sandbox]".

I've seen similar SO questions that mention that they created the sandbox user in the wrong country or had previously registered a valid existing account.  None of these are applicable in my situation.

Anyone else running into this right now?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the other responses got deleted, but it started working yesterday morning.  It was an Apple related outage.  So if anyone finds this answer and has completed steps 1-4 above (make sure you do), wait a day or two and see if it works.